# Any faster method to move things in a circle?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, math

Currently I'm using Math.cos and Math.sin to move objects in a circle in my game, however I suspect it's slow (didn't make proper tests yet though) after reading a bit about it.

Are there any ways to calculate this in a faster way?. Been reading that one alternative could be to have a sort of hash table with stored pre-calculated results, like old people used it in the old times before the computer age.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Are these things moving at a fixed angular velocity or a possible set of fixed angular velocities? If you know there is a fixed velocity, you can precalculate sin(d_theta) and cos(d_theta) for a small d_theta corresponding to an angular velocity times time step size. Then you can use the trigonometric addition and subtraction identities to determine new cartesian coordinates using the existing coordinates and the precalculated values.

Comment: http://www.actionscript.org/resources/blogs/35/Mathsin-vs-OurSin.html and http://lab.polygonal.de/?p=205

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, if you don't have any angular acceleration (the angular velocity stays constant -- this is a requirement for the object to remain traveling in a circle with constant radius without changing the center-pointing force, e.g. via tension in a string), then you can use the following strategy:

1) Compute `B = angular_velocity * time_step_size`. This is how much angle change the object needs to go through in a single time step.

2) Compute `sinb = sin(B)` and `cosb = cos(B)`.

3) 
Note that we want to change the angle from A to A+B (the object is going counterclockwise). In this derivation, the center of the circle we're orbiting is given by the origin.
Since the radius of the circle is constant, we know `r*sin(A+B) = y_new = r*sin(A)cos(B) + r*cos(A)sin(B) = y_old * cos(B) + x_old*sin(B)` and `r*cos(A+B) = x_new = r*cos(A)*cos(B) - r*sin(A)sin(B) = x_old*cos(B) - y_old*sin(B)`.

We've removed the cosine and sine of anything we don't already know, so the Cartesian coordinates can be written as

`x_new = x_old*cosb - y_old*sinb`

`y_new = x_old*sinb + y_old*cosb`

No more cos or sin calls except in an initialization step which is called once. Obviously, this won't save you anything if `B` keeps changing for whatever reason (either angular velocity or time step size changes).

You'll notice this is the same as multiplying the position vector by a fixed rotation matrix. You can translate by the circle center and translate back if you don't want to only consider circles with a center at the origin.

#### First Edit

As @user5428643 mentions, this method is numerically unstable over time due to drift in the radius. You can probably correct this by periodically renormalizing x and y (`x_new = x_old * r_const / sqrt(x_old^2 + y_old^2)` and similarly for y every few thousand steps -- if you implement this, save the factor `r_const / sqrt(x_old^2 + y_old^2)` since it is the same for both `x` and `y`). I'll think about it some more and edit this answer if I come up with a better fix.

#### Second Edit

Some more comments on the numerical drift over time:

I did a couple of tests in C++ and python. In C++ using single precision floats, there is sizable drift even after 1 million time steps when B = 0.1. I used a circle with radius 1. In double precision, I didn't notice any drift visually after 100 million steps, but checking the radius shows that it is contaminated in the lower few digits. Doing the renormalization on *every* step (which is unnecessary if you're just doing visualization) results in an approximately 4 times slower running time versus the drifty version. However, even this version is about 2-3 times faster than using sin and cos on every iteration. I used full optimization (-O3) in g++. In python (using the math package) I only got a speed up of 2 between the drifty and normalized versions, however the sin and cos version actually slots in between these two -- it's almost exactly halfway between these two in terms of run time. Renormalizing every once in a few thousand steps would still make this faster, but it's not nearly as big a difference as my C++ version would indicate.

I didn't do too much scientific testing to get the timings, just a few tests with 1 million to 1 billion steps in increments of 10.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, not enough rep to comment.

The answers by @neocpp and @oliveryas01 would both be perfectly correct without roundoff error.

The answer by @oliveryas01, just using sine and cosine directly, and precalculating and storing many values if necessary, will work fine.

However, @neocpp's answer, repeatedly rotating by small angles using a rotation matrix, is numerically unstable; over time, the roundoff error in the radius will tend to grow exponentially, so if you run your programme for a long time the objects will slowly move off the circle, spiralling either inwards or outwards.

You can see this mathematically with a little numerical analysis: at each stage, the squared radius is approximately multiplied by a number which is approximately constant and approximately equal to 1, but almost certainly not exactly equal to 1 due to inexactness of floating point representations.

If course, if you're using double precision numbers and only trying to achieve a simple visual effect, this error may not be large enough to matter to you.

Comment: This is a good point, and I assumed it was for a visual effect so such errors would not matter, but I will note this in my answer.

Comment: I've done some numerical testing regarding this which I've added to my answer. The short story is that with single-precision floats you get in trouble surprisingly early, but the periodic renormalization seems to work. It may not save the OP that much in terms of computation time though, which would leave the code more accessible if the sine and cosine functions were just used as one would expect. Thanks again for bringing this up.

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with sine and cosine if I were you. They're the most efficient way to do what you're trying to do. If you really want maximum performance then you should generate an array of x and y values from the sine and cosine values, then plug that array's values into the circle's position. This way, you aren't running sine and cosine repeatedly, instead only for one cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility completely avoiding the trig functions would be use a polar-coordinate model, where you set the distance and angle.  For example, you could set the x coordinate to be the distance, and the rotation to be the angle, as in...

```
    var gameBoardPin:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var gameEntity:Sprite = new YourGameEntityHere();
    gameBoardPin.addChild( gameEntity );
```

...and in your loop...

```
    // move gameEntity relative to the center of gameBoardPin
    gameEntity.x = circleRadius;
    // rotate gameBoardPin from its center causes gameEntity to rotate at the circleRadius
    gameBoardPin.rotation = desiredAngleForMovingObject
```

gameBoardPin's x,y coordinates would be set to the center of rotation for gameEntity.  So, if you wanted the gameEntity to rotate with a 100 pixel tether around the center of the stage, you might...

```
    gameBoardPin.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
    gameBoardPin.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
    gameEntity.x = 100;
```

...and then in the loop you might...

```
    desiredAngleForMovingObject += 2;
    gameBoardPin.rotation = desiredAngleForMovingObject
```

With this method you're using degrees instead of radians.

Comment: That rotation uses internally Math.cos and Math.sin. You are not avoiding them, they are just used under the hood.

Comment: I can't argue for or against that, but I can advise that under load (thousands of DisplayObjects), the model I describe can be up to 50% faster.  The specific areas of efficiency are probably having to recalculate the radius, and having to put two calls on the stack for Math rather than one.  That is, even if they go to the same trig implementation, .rotation doesn't recalc based on radius, and makes a single "app-land" call to Math.  That doesn't mean my example is right for the job, but you will see speed improvements.